# Read a binary file using javascript and convert to charecter

Tags: javascript, node.js

Am trying to read a binary file and trying to convert it to a characters
here is the code
am not sure it is a proper way
Experts please correct me

```
var fs = require('fs');   
fs.readFile('C:/parsing/test.prn',  function (err, data) {
    bufferString = data.toString();     
    bufferStringSplit = bufferString.split('\n');  
    var byteArray = getBytes(bufferStringSplit[50]); // converting to byte array
    console.log(byteArray.length)


    var result1 = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
        console.log(byteArray[i],"-----------------byte array")
        result1 += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(byteArray[i], 2)); // converting to charecter
    }
});

function getBytes(str) {
    var bytes = [], char;
    str = encodeURI(str);

    while (str.length) {
        char = str.slice(0, 1);
        str = str.slice(1);

        if ('%' !== char) {
            bytes.push(char.charCodeAt(0));
        } else {
            char = str.slice(0, 2);
            str = str.slice(2);

            bytes.push(parseInt(char, 16));
        }        }

    return bytes;
};
```

Another code i used

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.open('C:/parsing/test.prn', 'r', function(err, fd) {
var result ="";
  if (err)
    throw err;
  var buffer = new Buffer(100);
  while (true)
  {   
    var num = fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, 1, null);
    if (num === 0)
      break;
    console.log('byte read', buffer[0]);
    result += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(buffer[0], 2));
  }
  console.log(result)
});
```

`console.log(result)` prints as follows

> ♥☺ ☺ ☺☺ ☺☺  ☺☺ ☺☺       ☺☺ ☺☺  ☺☺  ♥☺☺ ☺☺ ☺☺ ☺☺☺☺☺☺  ☺  ☺☺ ☺☻☻ ☺☻☻☻☺☻  ☺  ☺ ☺☺☺☺ ☺ ☺ ☺ ☺☺☺☺  ☺ ☺☺  ☺☺☺ ☺☺  ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥  ♥☺        ☺☺☺☺☺  ♥☺☺   ☺

Comment: You will not be able to convert it with a simple code. It's format is too complex... Also, Duplicate with your own question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27958720/parse-a-prn-file-using-node-js

Comment: is any other ways to do this using javascrtipt or node.js i searched in google but not get any possible solution

Comment: what do you mean? the content of the binary file is text? how is it coded?

Comment: No, you would need to emulate a printer, since prn file contains coords of points to print if I remember correctly + some metadata - not text.